# Algorithm to generate random testcases for histogram distance

Tags: algorithm, testing, histogram, distance

I've written my own implementation of [EMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) histogram distance in Java.

Please see this example of input and output:

```
 h1 = mapOf(5 to 0.5, 7 to 0.5)
 h2 = mapOf(2 to 0.3, 8 to 0.7)

 emd(h1, h2) evaluates to 2.0
```

Now, I'd like to generate random tests for it to check its correctness.

Is there a good approach to generate two histograms of most general form (arbitrary number of items, non-trivial items) with known EMD between them?

It would also be acceptable to generate a pair of histograms `h1`, `h2`, calculate `emd(h1, h2)`, then modify `h1` to `g1`, `h2` to `g2` and check how `emd(g1, g2)` differs from `emd(h1, h2)`, but again, I need a way to modify `h1` and `h2` so that the EMD changes in a predictable way.

I tried to find the most similar keys `k1` and `k2` in `h1` and `h2` respectively and add `C` to both `h1[k1]` and `h2[k2]`, expecting that `emd(h1, h2)` would change by `C`, but it didn't always seem to hold.

My implementation can use histograms with any types of keys provided a metric for them, but `int`s with `Math.abs(x - y)` metric will be enough for testing.

Comment: You can hand-calculate simple cases, e.g. where all the weight of each distribution is concentrated on a single value. You can also generate two completely arbitrary distributions and check that if you reflect both of them the distance between them is unchanged. This distance appears to obey the triangle inequality (check - see http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/99/1620/CS-TR-99-1620.ch4.pdf P 5) so you could also produce three arbitrary distributions and check this.

Comment: @mcdowella, I already have tests for symmetry, subadditivity and simple tests like those with single non-zero value. Now looking for a way of testing more general cases. Anyway, thanks for you advice.